# Bug with embedding fonts in Flex - panel's title won't show up

Tags: apache-flex

Good morning,

I face a curious bug as I try to set a fontstyle in a mx:Panel object in Flex.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Panel xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"    
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
          layout="absolute" title="Test"
          titleStyleName="titleAssumed" >


    <mx:Label x="0" y="-5" styleName="othersAssumed" />
    <mx:Label x="0" y="16" styleName="othersAssumed"/>
```

The associated CSS file contains the following relevant styles:

```
/* CSS file */
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

@font-face{
    src: url("ttf\\ControlSign Bold.ttf");
    fontFamily: ControlSign;
    fontWeight: bold;
}

@font-face{
src: url("ttf\\ControlMono Regular.ttf");
fontFamily: ControlMono;
}

.titleAssumed
{
fontFamily: ControlSign;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12;
color: #FFFFFF;
} 

.othersAssumed
{
fontFamily: ControlMono;
font-size: 15;
color: #ADADAD;
}
```

With this configuration, and once I have set the compiler properties in Eclipse for the compiler to use the Flash text engine for MX components, I can see the two labels of the Panel in the correct font and style ; but the Panel's title will not show up. Even if I add the "embedAsCff: false" line to my style .titleAssumed, the title refuses to show up.

Any idea about what could be causing the trouble? Thanks !

EDIT: syntax error fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set embedAsCFF: true in your font. Also you have a syntax error where you are not closing your curly brackets on the fonts. Below is an example and here are [some more](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/10/15/embedding-fonts-in-flex-gumbo/).

```
@font-face{
    src: url("ttf\\ControlSign Bold.ttf");
    fontFamily: ControlSign;
    fontWeight: bold;
    embedAsCFF: true; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The syntax error comes from my copying the code into the SO question. I already tried putting embedAsCff as true in the css but it did not change anything..